# Forward external traffic to 127.0.0.1

Tags: iptables

I have an HTTP server running on 127.0.0.1:8000.  How can I use iptables or something to route external traffic to it?  I want to be able to access my.ip.addr:8000 from my browser.

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8000 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8000
```

does not help

**EDIT:**

To test whether or not this works I am using the following node.js script:

```
// Load the http module to create an http server.
var http = require('http');

// Configure our HTTP server to respond with Hello World to all requests.
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.end("Hello World\n");
});

// Listen on port 8000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
server.listen(8000, "127.0.0.1");

// Put a friendly message on the terminal
console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/");
```

Comment: `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8000 -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:8000` and 
`iptables -I FORWARD -i eth0 ! -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 8000 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: I am guessing that these are two commands.  Unfortunately, they did not help.

Comment: the ip_forward sysctl is enabled? `sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward`

Comment: net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need iptables for this, the simplest way is to change the IP address on the "server.listen" line. It can either be the public IP or "0.0.0.0". The latter will bind the web server to all available IPs.

Your other choice is to use another web sever set up in a proxy configuration. Nginx or Apache httpd works well for this.

Comment: Setting 0.0.0.0 is not actually possible with the real server.  I was just using Node.js for testing.

Comment: Thats why I gave you two solutions :) If you can't bind an IP address other than localhost, use a proxy. Setup Nginx (or whatever) on the same machine as the "real server" it will be able to bind to any/all of the IPs and proxy the http traffic to localhost. This such a common usage pattern they mention it in the beginners guide. http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html#proxy

Answer (score 1):

`REDIRECT` does not redirect connections to `127.0.0.1`, that would not work because `127.0.0.1` cannot be used to communicate with the client IP.

`REDIRECT` redirects the traffic to the IP address of the interface, which the packets are arriving on. You have to either explicitly listen on that IP address or bind to the any address  `0.0.0.0`.